# The type or namespace name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I've created a project using the Visual Studio *.NET Core 2.1 SDK + React Template*.

I'm met with the following error when running the project:

> One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure that your project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the 'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.

> The type or namespace name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace 
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

[image]

I've done what research I could and have tried the following to no avail:

- `dotnet restore` in Package Manager Console
- Deleting my `bin` and `obj` folders
- Opening `_ViewImports.cshtml` and adding a `@using` for *every namespace in my solution*

If I modify the `HomeController Index()` from returning the `View()` to instead `[HttpGet] public string Index() => "Hello World!";`, the text is returned without any error.

---

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div id="react-app">Loading...</div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

---

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace sample_project.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            ViewData["RequestId"] = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Shortly after posting this I've solved the issue.

I had upgraded my project to .NET Core 2.1 but one of the references (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`) was version `2.0.8`.

Upon updating this to `2.1.0`, the project now works as expected.

Comment: Thanks! I did something similar. I upgraded 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.All' from 2.0.8 to 2.0.9 and nothing warned me that I had to target Core 2.1.

Comment: Had to update Microsoft.AspNetCore and Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC, both to 2.1, then it worked for me.

Comment: Do note that the recommended approach after 2.1 is to _not_ set a version on the meta package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`, instead it will be inferred from what you specify in `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>`. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 8):

I am following this tutorial to get started in .net Core:

[Getting Started with EF Core on ASP.NET Core with a New database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db)

They use .net core 2, so I started my project in core 2. Previously, I installed core 2.1. When I scaffolded a controller according to the tutorial, I got this error. I found from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/771) the below solution which solved my problem:

[image]

In my visual studio package manager console, I ran following three commands:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All -Version 2.0.8
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 2.0.3
Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design -Version 2.0.1
```

Then I tried to scaffold a new controller again. This solved the problem. Works fine.

Comment: Dude. It helps me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Thanks, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

if you're using .Net Core 3.0 or above,
add this to startup.cs in your hosting project:
services.AddRazorPages();